# How to Save Checked Items in a Checked List box in Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, class, listview, checklistbox

I'm working on a game library app that adds the user's game collection to a listview, with multiple subitems to it.  I have one subitem which is a check listbox, that allows you to check off which platform or system the game is for.  I have code for the listview's selected index changed, which brings up the saved information for the game's title when you select the item in the listview.  However, I haven't been able to figure out how to save the information from the checked listbox and have it display the platforms previously checked off by the user when they select the specified game.   I have everything arranged in classes and my code is below.  I've tried writing out `f.platformCheckBox.CheckedItems.ToString() = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].platform;` in my `IndexChanged.cs`class, but it throws an error saying that "The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property, or indexer".  So I'm unable to do that.  Here's my code below, and if anyone has any suggestions as to how to save the contents of the checked listbox, I'd greatly appreciate it. Note: The IndexChanged class is located right at the bottom of the code, figured I might display all my code just in case I'm missing something important somewhere else in my code.

```
namespace GameLibrary
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public List<Library> Game = new List<Library>();
        public Library lib = new Library();

    public void saveBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Save save = new Save();
        save.saveChanges(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add add = new Add();
        add.addGame(this);
    }

    private void deleteBtnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delete delete = new Delete();
        delete.deleteGame(this);
    }

    private void gameList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IndexChanged Index = new IndexChanged();
        Index.selectedIndexChanged(this);
    }

    private void searchBttn_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Search search = new Search();
        search.searchLibrary(this);
    }
}
public class Library
    {
        public string gametitle
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string developer
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string publisher
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string platform
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
class Save
    {
        public void saveChanges(Form1 f)
        {
            if (f.gameList.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].gametitle = f.titleText.Text;
                f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].developer = f.developerText.Text;
                f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].publisher = f.publisherText.Text;
                f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].platform = f.platformCheckBox.CheckedItems.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
class Add
    {
        public void addGame(Form1 f)
        {
            f.lib.gametitle = f.titleText.Text;
            f.lib.developer = f.developerText.Text;
            f.lib.publisher = f.publisherText.Text;
            f.lib.platform = f.platformCheckBox.CheckedItems.ToString();
            f.Game.Add(f.lib);
            f.gameList.Items.Add(f.lib.gametitle);
            f.titleText.Clear();
            f.developerText.Clear();
            f.publisherText.Clear();
            foreach (int i in f.platformCheckBox.CheckedIndices)
            {
                f.platformCheckBox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
            }
        }
    }
class Search
    {
        public void searchLibrary(Form1 f)
        {
            foreach(ListViewItem item in f.gameList.Items)
            {
                if(item.Text.StartsWith(f.lib.gametitle))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
                    item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Selected = false;
                    item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
                    item.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
                    MessageBox.Show("Game title not found in library");
                }
            }
            if(f.gameList.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                f.gameList.Focus();
                f.titleText.Text = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].gametitle;
                f.developerText.Text = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].developer;
                f.publisherText.Text = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].publisher;
                f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Text = f.titleText.Text;
            }
        }
    }
class IndexChanged
    {
        public void selectedIndexChanged(Form1 f)
        {
            if(f.gameList.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            {
                f.titleText.Text = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].gametitle;
                f.developerText.Text = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].developer;
                f.publisherText.Text = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].publisher;
                f.platformCheckBox.CheckedItems.ToString() = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].platform; //This is where it throws the error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I stopped reading when I saw this: `f.platformCheckBox.CheckedItems.ToString() = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].platform;` You shouldn't be trying to cast the left hand side of an assignment to a string. Change it to: `f.platformCheckBox.CheckedItems = f.Game[f.gameList.SelectedItems[0].Index].platform;` and that may get rid of your exception. As for the "How to save checked listbox items", why not write them to a CSV or XML file and then read them back in when needed?

Comment: You may find this post helpul [Save CheckedListBox CheckedItems to Settings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773280/save-checkedlistbox-items-to-settings/32773371#32773371)